# Inheritance and CRTP

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

For practical reasons, I've got a class like

```
template <class A>
class CRTP
{
    template <int (A::*Member)()>
    int func(void * obj)
    {
        int result
        // Do something with Member, like
        // result = (reinterpret_cast<A*>(obj)->*Member)();
        return result;
    }
};
```

The `template <void (A::*Member)()>` is a requirement, it cannot be passed as an argument.

And I also have a class Base

```
class Base : public CRTP<Base>
{
    int aMemberOfBase() {...}
};
```

And its derived which I want to also inherit CRTP

```
class Derived : public CRTP<Derived>, public Base
{
    int aMemberOfDerived() {...}
};
```

In some member of Derived, I'll do something like

```
func<&Derived::aMemberOfDerived>(this);
func<&Base::aMemberOfBase>(this);
```

Is that possible ?

(Well, VC++ compile only the first line and don't want to read about the second one... but Derived should have the members

```
template <int (Base::*Member)()> int func(void * obj);
template <int (Derived::*Member)()> int func(void * obj);
```

which looks strange, I admit it. But the following piece of code

```
template <void (Base::*Member)()> int func() {return 0;}
template <void (Derived::*Member)()> int func() {return 1;}
```

compiles and return `func<&Base::someMember>() != func<&Derived::someMember>()`, because the signature of the template is not the same and can't be the same.)

I must admit that I'm not well award of what the standard says. But is the inheritance pattern I'm trying to make allowed? And if yes, why one of the line doesn't compile?

Moreover, if I declare

```
class Derived : public Base, public CRTP<Derived>
```

instead of

```
class Derived : public CRTP<Derived>, public Base
```

I get compile time error (on all the `func<...>(...)`), which means that there's something wrong somewhere.

On the other hand, I know that

```
template <class A, int (A::*Member)()> int func(void * obj)
```

would remove the need of a CRTP, but it's painfull to write `func<Derived, &Derived::aMember>()`. Is there a workaround like

```
template <class Class, void (Class::*Member)()> class A 
{
    void func(void * obj) {...(reinterpret_cast<Class*>(obj)->*Member)();...} 
};
template <typename Signature> class B;

template <typename Class, typename Member>
class B<&Class::Member> : public class A<Class, &Class::Member> {};
```

which would allow `B<&Base::Derived>().func(somePtrToBase)`?

Comment: Well, after reading unrelated articles, it seems that Don Clugston, in his "fastest delegate" encountered the same problems. So I decided to drop the CRTP and repeat the arguments. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can disambiguate by qualifying the name of the base member template. The following should work:

```
template <typename A> struct CRTP
{
    template <int (A::*Member)()> int func();
};

struct Base : CRTP<Base>
{
    int aMemberOfBase();
};

struct Derived : CRTP<Derived>, Base
{
    int aMemberOfDerived();

    void foo()
    {
        CRTP<Derived>::func<&Derived::aMemberOfDerived>();
        CRTP<Base>::func<&Base::aMemberOfBase>();
    }
};
```

I made everything public to avoid getting bogged down in access control details.

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to repeat myself. My question is "Can I avoid this repetition? If yes how. If no, why?"

Comment: Oh by the way, I tried to use public/private inheritance (`class Base : private CRTP<Base>`) to disable the use of `Base::fun<...>(...)` in the Derived class, so there couln't be any ambiguity, but the `class Derived : public Base, private CRTP<Derived>` don't work.

Comment: @Fred: Access check is performed *after* overload resolution, not before. Playing with `private` and `public` won't help.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks, that's one more thing I know now. But it should be useful (in that very case at least...) to do it _before_. but ok. Thanks for the info !

Comment: @Fred: Well, I'd re-engineer this to use an argument-deducing function template, like `f(&Base::aMemberOfBase, this)`.

Comment: One of the this I do is `template <void (Class::*Member)()> static void CallMember(void * onThis) {(reinterpret_cast<Class*>(onThis)->*Member)();}` so I can have a call to a member fonction of any class stored in a pair `void (*myCallToMember)(); void *myObjectOnWhichICallMyMember`. So unfortunately, I _can't_ re-engineer.

Comment: @Fred: Can't you provide another wrapper that calls `CallMember`?

Comment: I can. But to do so I have to do a `CreateCallMember<Class, &Class::Member>()`. I'm too lazy to write that (and I don't like to repeat myself, so writing Class twice is one time too much), so I tried to figure out a way to do so... and than ran into the CRTP / inheritance problem explained above.

Comment: @Fred: But the point is that you don't type anything, and use argument deduction.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I understand that you can deduce the type `Class`, but I have no hint on how I could make a template function  / class that would cause this deduction. Any hint?

Comment: @Fred: Never mind, you're right, you don't get around either repeating the base type or hard-coding a set of functions...